# How can we add functionality to a custom permission in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Django, I have been able to grasp, how we can add custom permissions to a particular Model in *Django*,the thing I am confused about, is once we have declared our permission, how do we add the functionality of the permission.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    my_file=models.Charfield(max_length=30, blank=False)
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_task", "Can see available tasks"),
            ("change_task_status", "Can change the status of tasks"),
            ("close_task", "Can remove a task by setting its status as       closed"),
        )
```

In the above code, we have declared the permissions, how do we write the functionality of these permissions.